# Gridsearchcv with multilabel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I'm working on multilabel emotion analysis and built a sequential multilayer model, then using Keras classifier and Gridsearchcv, I use the score function to evaluate the system. Then I tried to compare the results of the score with that from using predict_proba function followed by Jaccard_score with average =" micro" to suits multilabel, I expect to have the same results but actually, this didn't happen could anyone help in interpreting this.
My code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
# Use scikit-learn to grid search 
import sklearn
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model_multiclass(learn_rate, dropout_rate,activation):
    # Create model
    model=tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense( 300, kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(150,  kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(50,  kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(11, activation=activation))
   
    # Compile the model
    adam = Adam(learning_rate=learn_rate)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
### Loading train data
###################
# # create model

# # Declare parameter values
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model_multiclass, verbose=10)   
# Define the parameters that you wish to use in your Grid Search along
# with the list of values that you wish to try out
learn_rate = [0.001]
dropout_rate = [0.5]
batch_size = [ 60 ]
epochs = [20,60]
activation = [ 'relu', 'sigmoid' ]

print(sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()))
scoring={'jaccard':'jaccard_micro','F1_score': 'f1_micro'}
# Make a dictionary of the grid search parameters
param_grid =dict(learn_rate=learn_rate, dropout_rate=dropout_rate, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,activation=activation )
# Build and fit the GridSearchCV
print(sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()))
print("Tuning hyperparameters for accuracy")
grid = (GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,return_train_score='True', refit={'jaccard'},  cv=KFold(5), verbose=15))
grid_results = (grid).fit(X_all,Y_all)
# Summarize the results in a readable format
print("Best: {0}, using {1}".format(grid_results.best_score_, grid_results.best_params_))
print(grid.best_params_)
print(grid.best_estimator_)
means = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print('{0} ({1}) with: {2}'.format(mean, stdev, param)) 
print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
print("score",grid.score(X_dev,Y_dev))
y_pred=grid.predict_proba(X_dev)
y_pred_int=y_pred.round()
micro_multilabel_accuracy=jaccard_score(Y_dev, y_pred_int,average='micro')
print('micro_multilabel_accuracy',micro_multilabel_accuracy)    
and the output I got :
Best: 0.5518947958946228, using {'activation': 'relu', 'batch_size': 60, 'dropout_rate': 0.5, 'epochs': 20, 'learn_rate': 0.001}
{'activation': 'relu', 'batch_size': 60, 'dropout_rate': 0.5, 'epochs': 20, 'learn_rate': 0.001}
<tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x0000023885BBED30>
score 0.5350427627563477
micro_multilabel_accuracy 0.3984088127294982
```